# Can't add a rolling file appender with Log4j2.properties

Tags: log4j2, appender

I have a java application running in a docker container. I can't change the program but I can change the log4j2.properties file. I want to add a rolling file appender but when I do it I get this error:

```
ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender file_appender java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "shared_logs" "read")
```

Then I gave all permissions to my shared_logs folder

```
chmod 777 shared_logs
```

But the error is still there.
This is how I added the the appender:

```
appender.fa.type = RollingFile
appender.fa.name = file_appender
appender.fa.fileName = shared_logs/elastic.log
appender.fa.filePattern = shared_logs/elastic-%d{yyyy-dd-MM}-%i.log.gz
appender.fa.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.fa.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.fa.policies.type = Policies
appender.fa.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.fa.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.fa.policies.size.size = 500
appender.fa.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.fa.strategy.max = 5
```

"fa" stands for fileappender

Answer (score 0):

Well, you obviously still have a permissions problem. Your fileName is a relative file so where it is being created will be based on the currently directory of your app. That would typically be either the directory your app is in or the root directory. If it is the root directory and you are expecting it to be in your app this would explain the problem. If you add -Dlog4j2.debug to the startup options you would see where Log4j is trying to create the file.

Writing to log files in Docker Containers is also not usually considered a best practice. If you haven't already, I would suggest taking a look at [Logging in the Cloud](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html) on the Log4j web site.